# Proving the irrationality of the concatenation of the $n$th powers of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion, rationality-testing, perfect-powers

*Note*: The apostrophes are meant to separate different groups of digits. Like, $0.{1^2}'{2^2}'{3^2}'{4^2}'\cdots=0.14916\cdots$. I wasn't able to come up with something better.

It is easy to show $0.{1^n}'{2^n}'{3^n}'{4^n}'\cdots$ is always irrational: if it were not, we would find that the number of consecutive zeroes in its period would have a maximum, but obviously we can always get one more reaching a new power of $10$. 
When it comes to the powers of a single natural number $m\ne 0,1$, in general that is $0.{m^0}'{m^1}'{m^2}'\cdots$, the irrationality follows from the fact that the last $1,2,3,4,\cdots,l$ digits of such powers repeat with different periods, yielding no total repetition.

We then have Copeland-Erdos's constant $0.2357\cdots$, whose irrationality follows from Dirichlet's theorem. Does this work for the number $x$ whose decimal expansion is formed by concatenating the $n$-th powers of the primes? Or, do we have a different way?

Comment: What does $0.2^{n'}3 \cdots $ mean? Something like $0.2xxx3$?

Comment: @johannes: The apostrophes are meant to separate different groups of digits. Like, $0.{1^2}'{2^2}'{3^2}'{4^2}'\cdots=0.14916\cdots$. I wasn't able to come up with something better. :/

Comment: Ok thanks - that is clear... Nice question +1!!!

Comment: I think that the explanation of the notation should go at the top, not the bottom.

Comment: @columbus: Yeah, I agree, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Dirichlet's theorem
on primes in arithmetic progressions,
for any $k$
there are an infinite number of primes
of the form
$10^km+1$.

If you choose $k$ large enough
compared to $n$,
there will be
an arbitrarily large number
of consecutive zeros.
Therefore,
the number can not repeat,
and is therefore irrational.

Answer (score 3):

You can have arbitrary large sequence of $0$'s:

Suppose not, there is a period $k$ in the decimal expansion.

By Dirichlet's theorem, we have infinitely many prime numbers $p$ in the form
$$
p= a 10^{k+2} + 1.$$
Then

$p^n \equiv 1$ (mod $10^{k+2}$).